# Connect 2 ESP32 to Raspberry over bluetooth Serial

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, esp32, serial-communication

Hope you´re fine! and really hope you can help me on this.
I have 2 ESP32 and 1 raspberry. Each ESP32 has a button, when I press any of the buttons a message must be sent over bluetooth of each ESP32.

ESP32_1 MESSAGE: "1L 100 100 200 200"
ESP32_2 MESSAGE: "2R 100 100 200 200"

I could connect ESP32 and raspberry over bluetooth successfully using the following command in 2 different terminals:

sudo rfcomm connect 1 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (MAC1)
sudo rfcomm connect 2 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (MAC2)

What I need is that if I press button_1 of ESP32_1 the message 1 must be received in raspberry. Otherwise, if I press button_2 of ESP32_2 the message 2 must be received and print in the raspberry.

The issue is that when I press button_2 dont send nothing and when I press button_1 after that, is sending information of button_2 + button_1, it seems like the port is waiting for receive the info in the other one.

Here my Python code for Raspberry:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import serial
import time

Incoming_Data1 = ""
Incoming_Data2 = ""

bluetoothSerial1 = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm1", baudrate =115200) #Connecting to source 1
bluetoothSerial2 = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm2", baudrate =115200) #Connecting to source 1
print("Bluetooth Connected GBF")

def Flush_all():
  bluetoothSerial1.flush()
  bluetoothSerial2.flush()

while 1:

  try:
    Flush_all()
    Incoming_Data1 = bluetoothSerial1.readline()
    print(Incoming_Data1)
    Flush_all()
  except:
    Flush_all()

  try:
    Flush_all()
    Incoming_Data2 = bluetoothSerial2.readline()
    print(Incoming_Data2)
    Flush_all()
  except:
    Flush_all()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to avoid using rfcomm as it was [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) back in 2017

As outlined in http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/, a Serial Port Profile (SPP) Bluetooth client connection can be done with Python3 standard socket library (after doing the pairing in bluetoothctl).

The example in Kevin's blog could be extended to work for connecting to two devices. Maybe something like:

```py
import socket

serverMACAddress1 = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'
serverMACAddress2 = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'

port = 1  # Needs to match value used on the device you are connecting to
SIZE = 1024
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)

s1.connect((serverMACAddress1, port))
s2.connect((serverMACAddress2, port))

while True:
    data = s1.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        print(data)
    data = s2.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        print(data)

s1.close()
s2.close()
```

There is also the Bluedot library that helps to abstract some of the detail away:
https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/07/python-bluetooth-rfcomm-client-server.html

Comment: Thanks ukBaz for fast reponse, let me check and I´m gonna let u know. Thanks!!!